# how to specify signature length for java.security.Signature sign method

Tags: java, security, signature, sha256

For my application, I'm trying to sign some byte contents using java.security.Signature class. The problem I'm having is that signature is never generated at a fixed length. For instance, sometimes it is generated at a length of 135, 136 or 137 bytes. Is there a way to specify the length or some padding at the end? Any other ideas or comments are appreciated.

```
    private byte[] ecdsaSign(ECPrivateKey key, byte[] content) throws Exception {
                Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "SC");
                ecdsaSign.initSign(key);
                ecdsaSign.update(content);
                byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
                return signature;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For ECDSA* Java crypto uses the **ASN.1 DER encoding** standardized by X9.62, SEC1 and [rfc 3279 sec 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.2.3), which **varies slightly in length**. This is covered in more detail on another Stack: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/how-can-i-convert-a-der-ecdsa-signature-to-ASN.1 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/shouldnt-a-signature-using-ecdsa-be-exactly-96-bytes-not-102-or-103 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37528/why-do-openssl-elliptic-curve-digital-signatures-differ-by-one-byte

This is also true for DSA, but not RSA, where signatures (and cryptograms since RSA supports both signature and encryption) are fixed length for a given key, as defined by I2OS and OS2I in PKCS1.

If you want a different encoding, such as the fixed-length one used by PKCS11 (and your provider name "SC" suggests that possibility), you must convert it.

**Added 2019-10:** you no longer have to do it yourself in Java; BouncyCastle since 1.61 (2019-02) *correctly* supports this, as does SunEC in Java 9 up (2018-12). See later near-dupe [Java ECDSAwithSHA256 signature with inconsistent length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122705/java-ecdsawithsha256-signature-with-inconsistent-length) .

Comment: Thanks for the response. Really appreciated. I was following a similar approach such as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385718/der-decode-ecdsa-signature-in-java. I can obtain fixed length R and S values after encoding to ASN1, but this gives me two values. Is there a way to encode these two values into one fixed length sequence like in base64 or other format?

Comment: @JoelPou: if you need to interoperate with any other program(s) or system(s), you need to use a format compatible with it(them), otherwise you can use any format you like that correctly preserves the values of r and s. The PKCS11 approach is one way, but there are probably hundreds or thousands of other possibilities. Base64 is not a format itself, it is an encoding that can be applied to any format. As one example XMLDSIG uses base64 of concatenated fixed-length r and s.